# Show total number of items in a PyroCMS Stream in menu item

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I'm using PyroCMS Pro 2.2.6 and I would like to show the total number of items in a PyroCMS Stream in a menu item; specifically I would show dynamically the number of reviews in database.

I tried various things that didn't work:

1.) I added an Entry Looping tag (http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/plugins/streams/entry-looping) which was cut because the menu item field isn't large enough:
{{ streams:reviews where="`review_status`='1'" }}{{ total }}{{ entries }}{{ /entries }}{{ /streams:cycle }}
[image: Entry Loop Tag added to Menu Item]

2.) I used the Variable module and created a variable for the Entry Looping tag which I added to the menu item: {{ variables:reviews_total }}. In the menu nothing was shown.

3.) I used the Widget module and created a widget instance for the Entry Looping tag which I added to the menu item: {{ widgets:instance id="10"}}. In the menu nothing was shown.

That's how the menu should look like whereas "23" should show the number of records in my stream:
[image: Menu Item with dynamic review number]

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Many thanks,

Philip

Comment: I think this is something that you should solve with JavaScript. Add a class to the link - review-count or something - grab the count with an ajax call and add it to the link. If you think that might be something you'll like, I can answer with some code examples an a general outline. But it's a fairly standard thing.

Comment: I prefer to use a rock-solid solution based on LexTags that is also search engine friendly. I don't want to use JavaScript.